# `manage.py runserver` and Ctrl+C (Django)

Tags: python, django, signals

When I quit Django `manage.py runserver` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, do threads running HTTP request finish properly or are they interrupted in the middle?

Comment: I believe Ctrl+C kills the process and all sub-processes related to the main thread. So they would be interrupted in the middle.  You can probably use ps -eLf (linux, unix) to list all the threads as a means to double confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** running HTTP requests are stopped when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is hit on the django dev server

I thought your question is really interesting and investigated:

I made a view that takes 10 seconds to execute and after that sends a response.
To test for your behaviour I stopped the development-server `manage.py runserver` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and checked for the results.

My base test:

```
class TestView ( generic.View ):
    def get ( self, request ):
        import time
        time.sleep(10)
        response = HttpResponse('Done.')
        return response
```

- Normal execute (10s runtime): Displays the msg `Done.`
- interrupted execute (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while the request is running): Browser error, the host cannot be reached

so far everything as expected. But I played around a little bit, because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in python is **not a full stop**, but actually handled rather conveniently: As soon as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is hit, a `KeyboardInterrupt` aka **an Exception is risen** (equivalent to this):

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt()
```

so in your command-line based programm you can put the following:

```
try:
    some_action_that_takes_a_while()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('The user stopped the programm.')
```

ported to django the new view looks like that:

```
def get ( self, request ):
    import time
    slept_for = 0
    try:
        for i in range( 100 ):
            slept_for += 0.1
            time.sleep( 0.1 )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    response = HttpResponse( 'Slept for: ' + str( slept_for ) + 's' )
    return response
```

- Normal execute (10s runtime): Displays the msg `Slept for: 10s`
- interrupted execute (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while the request is running): Browser error, the host cannot be reached

so no change in behaviour here. out of interest i changed one line, but the result didn't change; i used

```
slept_for = 1000*1000
```

instead of

```
time.sleep( 0.1 )
```

so to finally answer your question: on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the dev server shuts down immediately and *running http-requets* are **not finished**.

Comment: By default, `manage.py runserver` uses daemon threads to serve responses, which means that the complete process shuts down as soon as the main thread finishes, and it won't wait for any daemon threads to finish. Since the `KeyboardInterrupt` is triggered in the main thread, which isn't serving any responses, you can't capture it in your view, and the process with all daemon threads quits immediately. That's why your second example still doesn't finish the response.